# How can I know user speed scrolling with UIScrollView ??

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

How can I know user speed scrolling with UIScrollView ?? Can it possible ??

Answer (score 0):

The scroll view [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) methods should tell you all you need to know about scrolling motion.